# How to submit buttons via textboxs array

Tags: javascript, php, button, textbox, submit

I want to create a page with about 300 textboxs from a foreach loop. I am able to write links into the textboxes, but i can't read textboxes array. Buttons are not working. How to submit these links via buttons?

```
echo "<form><input style='width:1000px' type='text' name='link[]' value='https://example.com/api/user_api.php?request=SellItem&amount=" . $number . "&featured=0&classid=" . $item["classid"] . "&instanceid=" . $item["instanceid"] . "&key=xxx'". "<br>";
echo "<input name='Launchlink[]' type='button' value='Send' onclick='location.href=this.form.elements['link[]'].value'></form>'";
```

Comment: type='submit' and get rid of of onclick

Comment: thanks but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In light of your comments

```
var links = <?=json_encode($the_link_array)?>;
function open_all_of_the_links(){
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
        window.open(links[i], "_blank");
    }
}
document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener("click", open_all_of_the_links);
```

And then you can have anything with an ID of "theButton" and that'll register an event on it and should open all of the URLs in new tabs.

```
<span id="theButton">Click here to make all of your dreams come true</span>
```

Comment: Something wrong. it adds the link at the end of my current page. Like that: http://localhost/test.php?link%5B%5D={link}

Comment: @ozbackgammon what do you want it to do, then?  It's not terribly clear from your question.  I mean, that's submitting the link as a member of an array called links, which is what it looked like you wanted.

Comment: i want to open new tab these links when i click button. Thats it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It should work. But my problem is something else now. "Uncaught ReferenceError: links is not defined". I can't define name='links[]' array. Do you know why?

Comment: 'links' would be the name of the array of URLs that I thought you had handy. If it's a PHP array, you can json_encode it into the output. I'll add that to the example.